# Publish to topic from file

Tags: ros, can, rosbag, udpros, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite new to ROS. I have a logfile (format: .pcapng) and I want to write a node which receives the logged udp-packets (as a simulation; later, the node should receive these packets from a CAN). My problem is the following: I know how to write a subscriber-node, but how can I make the file publishing the packets (as messages) to a topic?

I have read something about ROS bags, but I am not sure whether they are the way to go. I would prefer some kind of programm with which I could play the file, so that I simply had to write the subscriber node.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221828/publish-to-topic-from-file/) by [Victoria_W](https://answers.ros.org/users/25224/victoria_w/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bit more complex, but the  `velodyne_driver` node just does that (ie: it uses a `pcap` file as stand-in for a connection to an actual device).

See [ros-drivers/velodyne/velodyne_driver/src/lib/input.cc, L187-L304](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/d48c203e3bcbca364254bb25a72ab71e30388ba6/velodyne_driver/src/lib/input.cc#L187-L304), which is then used in the [velodyne_driver/src/driver/driver.cc, L89-L99](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/d48c203e3bcbca364254bb25a72ab71e30388ba6/velodyne_driver/src/driver/driver.cc#L89-L99) itself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0